# CodeIgniter: Display custom view instead of 'Database Error' message

Tags: codeigniter

How Can I show a custom view instead of the generic error attached in cases of the database going down unexpectedly?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In **applications folder** there is a folder named **errors**. There are all `error files` which comes up when an error is occurred.

When **database error** is occured, **error_db.php** file is shown in browser. You can edit it or replace that with your custom file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sir, there is no folder named errors in the application directory.

Comment: @ankitsuthar if you are not seeing errors folder in `application/views` folder it means you are using CodeIgniter version 2.x. It will be available in CI 3.x versions.

Answer (score 6):

You should set `$db_debug = FALSE;` in your config database settings on your production server - you should NEVER show a raw database error message to your users, as it is a massive security risk